# Cannot access application running on JBOSS EAP 7 outside vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, jboss-eap-7, vagrant-windows

I am actually trying to access the application outside the vagrant box which is running on JBOSS EAP 7 server on port 8080. I did add the settings for port forwarding in vagrant file that is

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 8080
```

Port forwarding does shows in terminal log when i reloaded the vagrant. However when i access the application from browser outside of the vagrant box am getting error as ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on the browser. I also binded the address to 0.0.0.0 by running the below command but still no luck. Any suggestions please what i may be missing? I also did set the proxy settings but still no luck.

```
sudo ./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0
```

Below is the port binded with 0.0.0.0

[image]

Below is the log  for my vagrant reload

[image]
[image]

Below is the port forwarding i set in my ubuntu vagrant box
[image]

Below is the error on the browser

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found something that could help.

I'm using a RHEL 7.6 and the firewall was on:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --state
running
```

After disabling:

```
$ systemctl stop firewalld
$ sudo firewall-cmd --state
not running
```

I successfully access Jboss console from the outside